# choosing column to display phpmyadmin WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using WAMPServer 2,5 with MySQL 5.6.17 and phpMyAdmin 4.1.14 and I am trying to choose a column to display on a relational database.

when clicking table > structure > relation view 
I should see a "Choose column to display" option however I can't see it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use these extended features you need to create a some tables, configure a special user and activate these features in config.inc.php. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/QA_4_1/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage

Answer (score 0):

for displaying, creating relational database table and also for creating a database diagram you can use [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: This is not an answer, but I voted +1 because MySQL Workbench is much more productive tool than phpmyadmin.